# iOS Beginner: Screen orientation

Tags: iphone, ios

I've created a Window-based app, and added 2 UIView subclasses, one - the main window, the other - the content window.

I need my app to be in landscape mode. Now, here is what I've done:

- Added "**Initial Interface Orientation**" Key to project info, and set it to "**Landscape**"
- Set "**Supported Device Orientation**" to "**Landscape**"
- In both of my view .m files I returned **YES** in **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** function.

This does the work. However, when I switch between views, for some reason I see un ugly Portrait-based interface on a landscape mode, and the interface switches to landscape after like 2 seconds. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should return this in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}
```

This is where the app asks to the view if he can rotate to the new interfaceOrientation

Comment: I still get the same result. I think it has something to do with MainWindow.xib. Is there a way to put it in a landscape mode?

Comment: Yes, in the Interfaz Builder, in the properties of your view, you can change in the Simulated Metrics section, the value Orientation to Landscape

Comment: Or just `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);`.

Comment: The problem is that Orientations option is disable for MainView.xib in the interface builder, any ideas why this could be?

Comment: I really dont know, try with this guide and it will work: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Your views should return YES *only* for landscape orientation (`return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);`).